# Possible to buy this switch for my lawn mower?

Tags: switch, lawn-mower

My corded electric lawn mower stopped working today.  I'm pretty sure it is the switch pictured below since I can read voltage before the switch but not after.

My lawn mower is old enough that I can't find replacement parts online (it is a Homelite UT13118).

Is the switch from the lawn mower a more generally available switch such that I might be able to buy one?  Would be nice to be able to fix the lawn mower instead of trashing it.

[image]

Comment: It's on ebay for $12.

Comment: @batsplatsterson, could you share a link?  I searched for various stuff printed on the switch and couldn't get a match.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw it's an old listing, item sold.

Comment: you can use a light switch is you can't find a match; might work/act funny, but a switch is a switch; mind your current and you're fine, electrically.

Comment: @dandavis, great idea, but I'm not that motivated. :)  Also, the current lawn mower  is set up to shut off when you let go of the handle so a regular switch creates some safety issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Hit up electronic component suppliers like Mouser or Digi-Key.  They have a staggering catalog of switches and you are likely to find a match.

Prepare to spend a fair amount of time looking bleary-eyed at the mechanical drawings on data sheets to match the physical size.

It also helps to limit search to items they actually stock.  If it says 6 week lead time, nope.

Comment: It is a staggering catalog, but I wasn't able to find a match